# Memory issue iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've never encountered such issue before.. And now i don't know how to handle this, and hoping for some help.

I am pushing a view controller(lets say exampleViewController) to the navigation controller. In my exampleViewController on viewdidload i add an imageview with an image. On dealloc i remove this imageview from superview, then release any retained views. The instruments leak tool doesn't show any leaks, but when i open instruments- "activity monitor" and then i see that when i push my exampleViewController real memory increases in 5 MB, and when i pop my exampleViewController, memory only decreases in 3 MB.. So if i push and pop this exampleViewController a lot of times, i get a memory warning and after that app quits.

I'm definitely doing something wrong, because other view controllers behave as expected. So the problem is i don't know what am i doing wrong, and hope for you guys to suggest some ways of how i could track down what is causing this.

I have tried some tools in instruments like alloc tool and then marking heap, and some similar things, but that doesn't show what gets leaked :/

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:**

Now when marking heaps in instruments it seems executeFetchRequest: is leaking, Am i doing something wrong?

```
+ (Question *)getQuestionWithId:(NSString *)questionId
```

{
    Question *resultQuestion = nil;

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
//geting context from appdelegate
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

//form fetch request with predicate
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Question" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSPredicate *query = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"questionId=%@",questionId];
NSPredicate *query1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type='ke'"];

NSPredicate *predicates = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:query,query1, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicates];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

[fetchRequest release];
resultQuestion = [fetchedObjects lastObject];

return resultQuestion;
```

}

Comment: how about presenting the view modally?

Comment: So you are managing the memory manually and not using ARC, correct?

Comment: yes i am managing memory manually..
@Kobe.o4 i need to push this view controller, presenting it modally doesn't fit my needs :/

Comment: seems to me that you are not releasing the object you pass on in your notification. What do you do in your method where you handle the notification?

Comment: @Maverick1st no i am releasing it :/ Maybe you know some tools or methods which could help me track down the leak? Leak tool in instruments doesn't show leaks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be, that if your image is loaded with imageNamed, the cache doesn't get emptied on dealloc. Have you tried loading the image with 
`UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];`

instead of using

`myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]`

Of course this might only help "if" you use imageNamed.

Answer (score 0):

> ...On dealloc i remove this imageview from superview...

Never do this in `-(void)dealloc`, as this method is supposed for memory management.

Remove the imageview in `-(void)viewWillDissappear` instead (if you really need this). As about your problem, [read this](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/), I believe your issue is somewhere beyond the imageView you are talking about.

Comment: yes its not that, but why can't i remove it in dealloc?
As i understand if i add a view as a subview it gets retained, so in my dealloc i remove it from superview, and this decreases its retain count, and it then is 0, so the view gets released..

Comment: This would work if dealloc would be called everytime you pop your viewcontroller. But this is not the case. Dealloc only gets called, if you receive a memorywarning afaik. So if you want to be sure, that your viewcontrollers views are released properly you should do this in viewDidDisappear.

Comment: @Maverick1st, you make me laugh, dealloc is get called when all the instances of the class have been released. -(void)viewDidUnload is getting called on memory warning.

Comment: @Lukas, removing from superview is not the best way of memory management. If you have allocated that imageView ivar, just release it in dealloc (if it's a synthesized property, say self.myImageView = nil in dealloc), but do not consider releasing it by removing it from superview

Comment: Ok, i was a bit unprecise. What i learned is, that, if you set a breakpoint in dealloc, it will not get called if you just pop a viewcontroller. Don't ask me why, but it got only called in my apps, when i received a memorywarning. But that might be, because i used ARC and did not manage my Memory manually. I agree with you that you should use dealloc only to release your views and not to remove them form the supervies.

Comment: @Maverick1st, when you use ARC, you don't need to use -(void)dealloc. ARC does all the job.

Comment: I hat the case, that when using ARC and not setting the delegates of some webviews or tableviews to nil in dealloc, my app crashed, when i ran into memory issues. Thats why i use dealloc even if ARC should do all the job.

Comment: well, I bet you are right, as about me, I skip using ARC - doing the mem management manually is better for me.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea But why is that bad? E.g i allocate the view and add it as a subview, then release the view. So retain count now equal to 1, o don't own the object anymore, latter i remove it from superview and its retain count decreases to 0 so it gets released. Am i understanding it wrong?